# AJAX called routine doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can AJAX be used to execute code on a separate html page?

On a calling page I have the code

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'ajaxcalled2.html', //This is the current doc
     type: "POST",
     async: 'false',
dataType: 'json', 
     data: {username: "ABC123", season: "Winter", email: "winter@northpole.com"},
     complete: function(response){
         console.log(response);
     }
});
```

On the called page I have the code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('here');
</script>
</html>
```

The calling page goes to the complete function, so there doesn't appear to be a problem with that page

I can bring up the called page, and the alert is successfully displayed.

But putting them together, no alert is displayed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Trialing different options, chose to use the getscript option.

Set up global values in the calling program, which can be accessed in the called program

username = 'myname';

```
$.getScript("http://<domain>/ajaxcalled.js", function(){

 alert("Script loaded and executed.");

})
```

The called js simply has

```
alert('hi');
alert(username);
```

Username successfully displayed.